# Allow admins to control Django ORM through a view

Tags: python, django

I want to expose ORM control to my users. I don't mean I want them to add stuff to part of the code, I mean I want to actually allow them to write django code. I only need to allow specific models, and only allow fetching of data (not add or change anything). There'll be like a console and each line will be executed (sort of like ipython notebook), and the returned data (if it's a QuerySet object) will then be displayed in a table of some sort.

This feature will only be available to my super-user admins and so won't be a security concern. What's the best way to do this (if at all possible)?

**update**

Maybe I should give some background for the intended usage here. See I have built an app that collects and saves statistical information. My users have many filters I have built for them, But they constantly ask for more and more flexibility, sometimes they need to filter on something very specific and it's only a one-time thing, so I can't just keep adding more and more features.

Now my superusers know a little python, and I got the idea that maybe I can give them some sort of way to filter on their own. The idea is they will be able to save queries and name them, then adding those custom filters to a list present on the main site.

The way it would work is they get a QuerySet object containing all objects, which they can filter using a list of pre-determined commands. After running the command, the server will evaluate it, look for errors or forbidden code, and only then will run it. But I'm guessing I can't just use `eval()` in a production server, now can I? So it there some other way?

Comment: There is no good way to do this.

Comment: Maybe have Django manage a second database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add file on server `/usr/local/sbin/djshell`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/project/
/path/to/python /path/to/project/manage.py shell #or "dbshell" or custom interactive task
```

Add users with this shell

```
useradd -s /usr/local/sbin/djshell -g www-data [more options] superdjangoadmin
```

Allow login via ssh. User connects directly to django shell, types `from app.models import *` and thats all you need.

From this shell users can break accessible data. You must ensure that all data is read-only.
Maybe run this with copy of settings.py with DATABASES setuped with read-only username.

Pseudocode of *custom shell*:

```
#imports
command = input()#expecting "filter(...).last()" or so
cleanup(command) #remove ";", "eval()", escape parameter values, strip
command = "MyModel.objects." + command
try:
    result = eval(command)
    prettyprint(result)

except Exception as e:
    print get_traceback()        
    print e.message
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer if I want to actually give them shell control, but that's not exactly what I need. I want them to have some simplification of the basic filtering capabilities to allow custom query creation.

Comment: @yuvi write the custom shell =)

Comment: My own custom shell that is? Not a bad idea. I'll think about it

Comment: It isn't what I ended up doing, but i liked the solution a lot, and it's the right approach for a truly console-type control I have mentioned in my question. Thanks!

Comment: @yuvi updated with that i meant saying "custom shell"

Answer (score 1):

> I want to actually allow them to write django code

This means giving certain users access to write Django, and by extension Python, code. Short of giving your admin users terminal access to the code on a live machine this is impossible. If you did given the terminal access to the code, that *would* be a security issue as a simple syntax error could bring the entire site down.

Additionally, if you did this, every change by a user would require a resync of the database, and there is a real risk they might make a change to the model that `syncdb` or even [South](http://south.aeracode.org/#) couldn't handle meaning your data is irretrievable and the site non-functional.

Redesign your application so the level of flexibility can be done by changing instances of objects not the object code itself.

Comment: Thanks. A few notes though - 1. First of all, when I say django code, I only mean an abstraction of it. They won't get the models themselves but, say, a QuerySet object of `MyModel.objects.all()` which they would be able to filter (and nothing else) 2. I'm only intending to expose a small part of the API, and evaluate it myself with a white-list before running it 3. I'm not seeing a problem with Error handling, since I can scan for those and simply not return anything back (or return traceback in textual format)

Answer (score 0):

If admins know SQL - give them `phpmyadmin` with read-only privelegies.

Comment: They don't, though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After messing around a bit, I realized I am looking for something a lot more simpler than I thought. Here's a quick idea of how this looks (Item is a test model with two fields, email and name):

server-side:

```
def qs_eval(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    code = ''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        code = request.GET['code']
        cleaned = map(lambda x: x.strip(), code.split(','))
        commands = dict([x.split('=') for x in cleaned if x])
        items = items.filter(**commands)        

    return render_to_response('qs_eval.html', {'items': items, 'code': code})
```

html:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='code' value='{{ code }}' />
    <button cls='btn'>send!</button>
</form>

<table class='table'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for i in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.email }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously, there's no error-handling here, and I'm only allowing for filtering, but it's easy to expand this to other functionalities such as exclude and more, and pythonically checking the code for any no-no's etc.

Anyway, this is what I ended up doing. I'm still gonna mark @eri's suggestion as the answer, seeing how for a truly and complete console-type control that would probably be the right direction

Comment: It is not suitable for complex queries

Comment: I never said I needed complex queries

Comment: limiting and aggregating is often needed